# Counsel M-x always shows "^"

Tags: search, counsel

I installed Counsel/Ivy/Swiper and so far everything works fine. But when I call counsel-M-x via key bind M-x an "^" char is always added. I have no clue why this is happening and how to get rid of it (it does not interfere with the counsel-M-x command, it is just annoying). I'm using emacs on OS X and remapped the Meta key to the Command key `(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)`, but even with Alt as standard Meta key "^" is automatically inserted when calling counsel-M-x.

[image: Counsel-M-x]

I use the basic settings provided [here](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper)

```
(ivy-mode 1)
(setq ivy-use-virtual-buffers t)
(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'counsel-M-x)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`ivy-initial-inputs-alist` is a variable that controls the default minibuffer contents when using ivy (which is used by counsel).

The default `"^"` string means that if you type something immediately after this string only completion candidates that begin with what you typed are shown.

You can remove this default string in `counsel-M-x` command with:

```el
(setcdr (assoc 'counsel-M-x ivy-initial-inputs-alist) "")
```

Or to remove this initial input in all commands:

```el
(setq ivy-initial-inputs-alist nil)
```

Comment: Just to be clear: if you do remove this, it will change the search behavior to match substrings. I think the default of matching only the beginning is useful, and you can just hit space if you do want to search for a `^ substring`.

Comment: @glucas I think your wording is a bit exaggerated - the search behaviour doesn't change (search behaviour is controlled by `ivy--regex-function`), it's the default initial input that changes. Everyone is free to their preferences there. I, for example, only keep the initial `^` for `man`/`woman`.

Comment: @Basil Fair point, thanks. I mostly wanted to make clear that this is not just a cosmetic change as the OP implies in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `ivy-initial-inputs-alist` to an empty string for `counsel-M-x` specifically can be done via the `M-x customize-option RET ivy-initial-inputs-alist RET` interface.

Shown here as a lisp-expression

```lisp
'((counsel-minor . "^+")
  (counsel-package . "^+")
  (counsel-org-capture . "^")
  (counsel-M-x . "")
  (counsel-describe-symbol . "^")
  (org-refile . "^")
  (org-agenda-refile . "^")
  (org-capture-refile . "^")
  (Man-completion-table . "^")
  (woman . "^"))
```